# Does any HDMI device send commands on CEC pin

Tags: i2c, hdmi

I'm using an IPTV set-top-box that is connected to my TV via HDMI cable. When I'm turn the IPTV on or off it does not affect on TV and the TV remains off or on. When I check the CEC pin by the oscilloscope it doesn't show any thing. I mean the state of pin is high (3.3V) and when I press the set-top-box remote buttons there are no pulses on the scope.

Am I testing the CEC pin right? I mean is it possible that the scope prob may affects on the bus?

Is it possible that my set-top-box do not use CEC? if yes is there any way to force the device to do that?

My main problem is that I need to use one remote control for both TV and set-top-box.

Also there are an I2C pins on HDMI, is there any packets that shows turning on or off the device? if yes maybe I can decode them by a micro-controller and command the TV to turn on and off.

Comment: I solved the problem based on two notes. first I had tested the set-top box by the LG TV, the note is that the LG TVs do not accept standby command on CEC (and my device doesn't send commands by another keys). second I checked the pin by the scope while it was not connected to TV, this note is that it seems that the CEC is working after the source device detect the sink device (I'm not sure that this is a rule or only my device acts like this). but finally by reading the pin while it was connected to the TV I found the signal and now I can read them by stm32 MCU to command my old TV!

Answer (score 3):

You'd need a detailed manual for the set-top box (or better still, call tech support) help to figure out is CEC control is an option that needs to be enabled in the IPTV box.

CEC is a 1-wire interface and this Arduino thread might help you: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=22327.0

If it turns out that you need to build your own external functionality to implement CEC control perhaps you could build an IR RX to use the commands from your IPTV remote. Or you might even be able to implement the TV CEC commands based on the IPTV box going from active-to-standby based on mains current detection.

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't have a detailed manual and their emails didn't respond (it's a Chinese model of t503 IPTV). Thanks for your good ideas but I need a robust way to detect power state of set-top box.

Comment: Your chances of getting detailed info on your box are essentially zero.  But you should be able to see +5V on pin 17 coming from the box.  Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI

Answer (score 0):

The HDMI spec shows that there should be +5V appearing on pin 17 of the output connector from the box.  Can't you simply look for the presence of the +5V?

Comment: Again unfortunately the device does not disconnect that pin in standby, I mean the device by pressing of the remote power button goes to sleep and in this mode that pin remains high(+5v).

Comment: Also I checked the I2C pins of HDMI in the spec, it seams only the source device (my set-top box) may ask the sink (my TV) for some information. So I can't ask my set-top box to distinguish if it is powered on.